# How to use $(this) in if/else statement

Tags: jquery, this

HTML:

```
<div class="form-checkboxes" id="edit-field-vozrast-value"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-vozrast-value-1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" name="field_vozrast_value[1]" id="edit-field-vozrast-value-1">  
    <label for="edit-field-vozrast-value-1" class="option">0-3 </label>
</div>

<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-vozrast-value-2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="2" name="field_vozrast_value[2]" id="edit-field-vozrast-value-2">  
    <label for="edit-field-vozrast-value-2" class="option">3-7 </label>
</div>

<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-vozrast-value-3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="3" name="field_vozrast_value[3]" id="edit-field-vozrast-value-3">  
    <label for="edit-field-vozrast-value-3" class="option">7+ </label>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $age = $('#edit-field-vozrast-value .form-type-checkbox label');
var $vinput = $('#edit-field-vozrast-value .form-type-checkbox input');

    $age.on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).parent().find('input').is(':checked') != true) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight'); 
    }
    });

    if ($vinput.is(':checked')) {
      $age.addClass('highlight'); // this adds class highlight to all checkboxes
    }
```

Logic for this code is following - when a checkbox has a checked value - add class highglight to it's label. But the problem there is when a checkbox has a checked value it adds 'highlight' class to all of the checkboxes, even if they don't have checked value. So how can i use something like `$(this)` in this case?

**UPDATED info.** When i click on a checkbox - my page reloads and "highlight" class dissapears, that's why i need to use latest if/else statement to apply this class again to a checkboxes with "checked" statement.

Comment: and the complete jQuery code.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If the checkbox is already checked, exclude it? Quite confusing.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, you [might not even need javascript for this](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/)

Comment: show your html please it may be helpful for us

Comment: You need to loop though the values anyway if you have multiple checkboxes. You can't do it with only one if test.

Comment: @Sudharsan it would be helpful/benefitual for him.. not for us.. :D

Comment: i just see a closing of labels.

Comment: Maybe you need to check JQuery prev() method for retrieving the previous element (your label) when an input is checked ... I didn't tried but it should work

Comment: updated the code, guys. Please, take a look

Comment: What is the use of the last `if()`, it gets executed on DOM ready. when no checkbox is checked

Comment: @ShaunakD, i use if/else statement because when i click on a checkbox page entirely reloads and my "highlight" class disappears, but with that if/else statement i can apply again "highglight" class to a checkboxes with "checked" statement.

Comment: *when i click on a checkbox page entirely reloads* ? Why? How?

Comment: @ShaunakD, because it's a filter. When i click on a checkbox - page reloads and showing only people of chosen age.

Comment: @MLeFevre, lol you were right, i don't need js here at all. Solved it by pure CSS. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#edit-field-vozrast-value .form-type-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    /* my styles here */
}
```

That's did a trick, thanks everyone!